# Formatting Google Sheet Dates Inconsistent

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have a sheet where various data is entered through a form. Dates are picked on the form using the standard date picker provided by Google Forms.

Some dates in a column I can change the date format but others don't.

What is odd is that when I copy this column into a new sheet and then try and change the format these stubborn ones then change correctly.

I have made a [copy of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vm3hzhgL9VLuUiOjR445IJVb6slRtw2RB0bGJz1Gor8/edit?usp=sharing) (editable) and removed private info and left the column in question. BTW: there are two other date columns and they have similar issues. The issues are not on the same row for most cases.  So it's not row related.

[Here's a short video](http://www.screencast.com/t/RJYb7BXltVpH) where I show how I try to change the date format on the "bad" sheet, then I copied the culprit date entry to another sheet and then I can format it.
I hope you can assist with a way to work around this *bug*.

Answer (score 1):

## Spreadsheet

The spreadsheet demo locale linked on the question is set to United States which use month-day-year sequence for dates. The value shown on the video is `25/03/2015` as the month valid values are from 1 to 12, it can´t be interpreted as a date value on the original spreadsheet.

It's very likely that the second spreadsheet, that converts the `25/03/2015` to date, has a locale that use day-month-year sequence for dates.

Looks that we can't be sure that "ambiguous" strings like `4/3/2015` are being converted to the correct date.

## Google Forms

Google Forms responses could be exported as a CSV file from the Google Form. At this time dates are being included in the CSV file as "yyyy-mm-dd", so could be more reliable to use the exported CSV file than the responses sent directly to a the original spreadsheet.

See [View and manage form responses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en) for details about how to download forms responses al CSV file.