# Google Sheets interpreting dates from CSV in a weird way

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, csv, google-sheets-import-csv

I'm opening a csv report in Google Sheets. The Google Drive preview shows the dates like this:

[image: google drive csv preview]

When I open this file in Google Sheets the dates now look like this:

[image: google sheets view of dates]

And if I try and convert the date to int and then date it works for some but not all:

[image: google sheets trying to convert to proper dates]

Any idea how I can extract just the date from these cells?

Comment: Related : [Date fields that refuse to be parsed/formatted](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125582/88163)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've worked it out. Google Sheets imports the date cell as text and then interprets that cell as a date. The Locale is set as UK so it can't handle the US format date. I had change the spreadsheet Locale to US, use the =TO_DATE(INT(A2)) formula and then create a custom format on that column to show the date in UK format.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your data is mixed or some cells have been formatted before entering your data.

**Debugging**

1. Use the [`ISNUMBER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296) function to check wether all your dates are correct.
2. Go to the top menu and `Format` > `Number` > `Automatic` and reformat your cells.

*(If you still have issues, please share a sample sheet)*