# How can I display Google Sheets dates as Month-Day with the underlying data in UTC format (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, date

I want to display a date in Google Sheets as Month-Day (e.g. Jan-10) with the underlying data as: `2021-01-10`

However in order to show `Jan-10`, Google Sheets defaults the underlying data to `01/10/2021` instead.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the format by going to
`Format` >`Number` >`More Formats` >`More date and time formats` and choose or create the one that meets your needs.

[image]

Comment: Notice your underlying data is 1/10/2021? How can that be changed?

Comment: This is what your question is about: I want to **display a date**... with the underlying data as: `2021-01-10` Also: *"However in order to **show `Jan-10`**..."*. So your question is answered. As for your comment on how to change the underlying data, **you cannot**. In any case I believe you should accept the answer so others can be helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets manages dates as serial-numbers, meaning that a date (as well a date-time, time, duration) are internally managed as numbers and what you see depends on the spreadsheet regional settings and the cell formatting.

You can find the explanation made by Google on [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

Other resources

- [Set a spreadsheet’s location & calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en)
- [Format numbers in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en)

Related

- [Change Google Sheets default date format with other locale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103958/88163)
- [Changing a date in google sheets from MM/DD to DD/MM without changing the values](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/133505/88163)